# Need help identifying a monospace font

Tags: fonts, font-identification

I have already tried many font-finding tools, but they do not seem to work. This font is not Menlo, nor is it Ubuntu 11(I tried looking that up).
[image]

Comment: Just to be clear: the font is from linux

Comment: Is this Ubuntu or a different Linux distro? SST Typewriter by Monotype is pretty close.

Answer (score 1):

DejaVu Sans Mono, at its 16.5pt.